# An integral which could be split into even and odd functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

I found this integral in an old book of mine :

> $$\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{1}{1+x^{2x}} dx$$
> where $|a| \lt 1$

A hint was given that we could split this integral into even and odd functions but I don't know how to. I tried using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-a%7D%5E%7Ba%7D+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E%282x%29%7D) for the same but it doesn't help me out. If the exponent of $x$ would have been $2n$ then it wouldn't have been a problem but that $2x$ in the exponent really drives me out. I don't actually want an answer to this problem, I just want the even and odd functions, the integral should be split into. Any help regarding the same is appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $x^{2x}$ even defined over $[-a,0]$?

Comment: Good point. I think they might mean $x^{2x}$ as in $(x^2)^x$

Comment: @Jakobian I also think that but still couldn't proceed

Comment: @Jakobian That's literally what $x^{2x}$ is defined as being by simple exponent properties... What else would they mean except $(x^2)^x$??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f(x) = (x^2)^x$ satisfies the equation $f(x)f(-x) = 1$, therefore this is a special case of the following:

> Let $f: [-a, a] \to \Bbb R$ be continuous with $f(x)f(-x)=1$ and $1+f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x$. Then $$ \int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{1+f(x)} dx = a \, .$$

*Proof:* With the substitution $x \mapsto -x$ we get
$$
 I = \int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{1+f(x)} \, dx = \int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{1+f(-x)} \, dx \\
= \int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+1} \, dx  = 2a - I
$$
which implies $I = a$.

*Alternatively* one can proceed as in [Jacobian's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4228229/42969) and show that
the even part of $g(x) = \frac{1}{1+f(x)}$ is
$$
 g_e(x) = \frac 12 \bigl(g(x) + g(-x) \bigr) = \frac 1 2
$$
and therefore
$$
 I = \int_{-a}^a g_e(x) \, dx = a \, .
$$

Comment: Nice answer (+1) but I am in a dilemma, whether to verify your answer or Jacobian's. Both answers are perfect and resolve my issue :)

Comment: @Smile: You are welcome! – It is completely up to you which answer to accept. As the question author, it is your privilege (or burden :) to decide which answer helped you most. And you need not justify your decision.

Comment: @Martin, actually $$\frac12\bigl(g(x)+g(-x)\bigr)=\frac12\,.$$ Could you correct that typo?

Comment: @Antonio: Yes, thanks.

Comment: @MartinR, do you agree with me when I say that the integral converges and is equal to $a$ for all $a\in\mathbb R\;?$ Actually the assumption $|a|<1$ is not necessary, is it ?

Comment: @Antonio: Yes, I agree with your comment on the other answer.

Comment: @MartinR, thank you very much.

Comment: @MartinR Alright, after lots of thought, I decided I will accept your answer because of the theorem you mentioned in your answer and elaborating on Jacobian's answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 9):

Interpreting $x^{2x} = (x^2)^x$ we have
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{1+x^{2x}} &= \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{1+x^{2x}}+\frac{1}{1+x^{-2x}}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{1+x^{2x}}-\frac{1}{1+x^{-2x}}\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{2}+ \cdots\end{align*} where $\cdots$ denotes the odd part. So $$\int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{1+x^{2x}}\mathrm{d}x = 2\int_0^a \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}x = a.$$ Note that the assumption $|a|<1$ is so that $x^{2x}$ is separated from $-1$, so the integral converges.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Jakobian, I cannot understand why you eventually has written that the integral converges because of the assumption $|a|<1$. I think that the integral would converge for all $a\in\mathbb R$ since $\left(x^2\right)^x>0$ for all $x\ne0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(x^2\right)^x=1$.

Comment: Your answer is perfect but I have decided to accept Martin's answer because of the theorem he mentioned. I hope you don't mind it :). Thanks again!